# Dot product with shapes (x) and (x, y)

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I am really new to numpy, so I am having some troubles understanding the dot product.

I have this simple piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((5))
B = np.ones((5,10))

A.dot(B)
# array([ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.])

A.dot(B).shape
# (10,)
```

I cannot understand what is happening in this code. I am a little confused, because it seems that a shape of `(10,)`is not a column vector, because the transpose is the same.

Is `A`being broadcasted? I thought that `A` should be broadcasted to the shape of `(5,5)`, so it could be multiplied with `B` and thus returning an array of shape `(5,10)`. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Numpy defines transposing as `news shape = reversed(old_shape)`,  for `shape=(5,) ` nothing happens.  You need `shape=(5, 1)` for a column vector.

Comment: so basically `np.ones((5))` is treated like `np.ones((1,5))` but without a nested list

Comment: yes like [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.] dot([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,,,,],

Comment: Let's just say numpy makes a difference between an 1-dimensional array and a 2d matrix with one column aka vector

Answer (score 0):

Numpy makes a difference between 1d arrays (something of shape `(N,)`) and an 2d array (matrix) with one column (shape `(N, 1)`) or one row (shape `(1, N)` aka column- or row-vectors.

```
>>> a = np.ones((5, 1))
>>> B = np.ones((5, 5))
>>> B.dot(a)
array([[ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.]])
```

Or unsing python 3.5 with numpy 1.10:

```
>>> a = np.ones((5, 1))
>>> B = np.ones((5, 5))
>>> B @ a
array([[ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.]])
```

If you have a 1d array, you can use `np.newaxis` to make it a row or column vector:

```
>>> a = np.ones(5)
>>> B = np.ones((5, 5))
>>> B @ a[:, np.newaxis]
array([[ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 5.]])
```

Both new row and column:

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> B = x[:, np.newaxis] @ x[np.newaxis, :]
>>> B
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16]])
```